# Filter Question List by Votes

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I would like to filter the question list to only show questions with a vote score greater than or equal to zero (or some arbitrary number)

Comment: Nice suggestion. I feel.

Comment: Do up votes determine a feature's chance of being implemented?  If so, will you upvote?

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
is:question score:n
```

(where n is the desired score) in the search field to show only questions with a score of n or above.

```
score:n    // show entries with score n or above (same as score:n..)
score:0..n // show entries with scores from 0 to n
score:..n  // show entries with scores up to n
```

To filter only new questions, use the created filter with a date:

```
created:yyyy-MM-dd
```

e.g.

```
created:2016-08-17
created:2016-08
```